# Find all continuous functions such that $f$ and $f^2$ both have an integral of 1 with respect to strictly monotonically increasing alpha

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The question I have is the following:

Let $\alpha$: [0,1] $\rightarrow$ R (real numbers) be a strictly monotonically increasing function with $\alpha(0) = 3$ and $\alpha(1) = 4$. Find all continuous functions f: [0,1] $\rightarrow$ R such that
$$\int_0^1 f d\alpha = \int_0^1 f^2 d\alpha = 1 $$
where $f^2$ is $f$ squared, not composition.

I am a bit confused on how to approach this problem. I would think this is only possible with the constant function $f = 1$,  but my idea was to use the definition of the upper and lower Riemann Stieltjes integral for some arbitrary partition to show the antiderivative of $f$ and $f^2$ must be equal. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The given equations imply that $$ \int_0^1 (f-1)^2 d\alpha\int_0^1 (f^2 -2f +1) d\alpha = 1-2+1 = 0 $$ But the LHS is $$\int_0^1 (f(x)-1)^2 \alpha’(x) dx =0$$ Since $\alpha’(x) \gt 0$, the integrand is $\ge 0$ and hence the only way for this equation to hold is for $$f(x) \equiv 1$$

Comment: Do we know that alpha is differentiable?

Comment: @broum  You tell me. $d\alpha$ would only make sense when it is.

Comment: From my understanding, it is possible to have Riemann Stieltjes integrals where $\alpha$ is not differentiable and is singular, such as the Heaviside function. So, the assumption that the integral of f $d\alpha$ is the same as f$\alpha$'dx only holds if alpha is differentiable. Does only increasing on a closed interval guarantee this?

Comment: @broum No, that statement could still hold while $\alpha$ is discontinuous. And what is meant by $\int f \, d\alpha$? Is it $\int f(\alpha(x)) \, d\alpha(x) $ or $\int f(x)\, d(\alpha(x))$?

Comment: the second option

Comment: We do know that $\alpha$ is invertible. So $\int fd\alpha = \int f(\alpha^{-1} (\alpha)) \, d\alpha $ and the same argument can be applied.